# How to change value in a nested YAML record using yq

Tags: awk, sed, yq

I am trying to change the `bind_host: localhost` to `bind_host: 0.0.0.0` where the `bind_host` is the 3rd layer nested value of YAML file
Current value of File

```
server:
  application_connectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8989
    bind_host: localhost
  request_log:
      appenders: []
  admin_connectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8990
    bind_host: localhost
```

Expected Output

```
server:
  application_connectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8989
    bind_host: 0.0.0.0
  request_log:
      appenders: []
  admin_connectors:
  - type: http
    port: 8990
    bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

I am trying

```
awk '
/:$/{
  flag=""
}
/server/{
  flag=1
}
flag && NF && (/bind_host:/){
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/);
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  $NF="0.0.0.0";
  print val $0;
  next
}
1
'   config.yml
```

EDIT: Adding image based on answer of @inian
[image]

Second Image
[image]

Comment: Hi! What have you tried?

Comment: question edited

Comment: do you want an answer with `yq` or `awk`? if `yq`, remove the other two tags

Comment: Are there cases in which there is a `bind_host: localhost` that you do not want to replace? If yes, how do we recognise them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) based solution then use the following snippet. It runs a `jq` filter to update all the objects inside `server` that contains `bind_host` to `0.0.0.0`. The `-y` flag ensures the result object is returned in YAML and not JSON

```
yq -y '.server |= ( with_entries ( 
                      if   .value[] | select( keys[] | contains("bind_host") ) 
                      then .value[].bind_host = "0.0.0.0" 
                      else empty end
                    )
                  )' yaml
```

If the modification looks as expected, use the `-i` flag i.e. `yq -yi` to save the modifications in-place.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. where I have to put the file name called `config.yml`? I replaced the `yaml` with my file name `config.yaml` but it is returning `unknown command "config.yml" for "yq"` error

Comment: Yes you did it right. Copy paste the command properly (leave a space after the ending single quote), you shouldn't see that error.

Comment: I just copy-paste and changed the `-y` tag with `-yi` and it is returning a long error starting with `Error: unknown command ".server |= ( with_entries (`

Comment: I am using the code in inside a shell script/sh file

Comment: I can't help you with it, if you don't show how you are copy pasting it. It should be simple issue with copy pasting the multi line script. I made it so, to make it more readable. You can try that in a single line `yq -y '.server |= ( with_entries ( if   .value[] | select( keys[] | contains("bind_host") ) then .value[].bind_host = "0.0.0.0"  else empty end ) )' yaml`

Comment: I have edited my question and added an image where you can find how I am using the code

Comment: @Devil'sDream: What error are you seeing? Remove the `-i` option for now and see if the output is displayed in terminal properly. Also confirm if the yaml file is in the same path as your script

Comment: Added another image in the question

Comment: Am I using the correct `yq`? https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/

Comment: @Devil'sDream: I can't help you further with your environment. I'm afraid, you need to fix it. Run some basic filters with `yq` to see if its working. See if there is something wrong with your installation

Comment: @Devil'sDream: What seemed to be the problem?

Comment: I even couldn't figure out but as per your previous solution, I know you may not be wrong. Probably I have issue with the environment. I solved it using `sed`. `sed -i -- 's/localhost/0.0.0.0/g' config-example.yml`

Comment: @Devil'sDream: the `yq` usage I'm talking about is https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

Answer (score 0):

Running

```sh
<input.yaml yq -y '((.server.application_connectors[].bind_host| select(.) ) |= gsub("localhost";"0.0.0.0") )' | \
yq -y '((.server.admin_connectors[].bind_host| select(.) ) |= gsub("localhost";"0.0.0.0") )'
```

you have

```yaml
server:
  application_connectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8989
      bind_host: 0.0.0.0
  request_log:
    appenders: []
  admin_connectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8990
      bind_host: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: While this may solve the problem, it isn't quite efficient, as it involves running `yq` twice

Comment: error `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'y' in -y
2020/05/29 13:07:32 unknown shorthand flag: 'y' in -y`

Comment: @Devil'sDream if your run `yq --version` what you have?

Comment: yq version 3.3.0

Comment: @Devil'sDream your are using another yq. The one I use it's at 2.10.1 release https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/releases